# Creating a collapsible div with nested links/buttons with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I would like to create a collapsible "card" with a row of buttons on the lower part of the collapsible div. A bit like a [twitter card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqUfM.png) which has a row of buttons on the lower side. In this example, the card itself is clickable (and I would like it to be collapsible). In my case, I would like there to be a little arrow on the right had side that indicates whether the collapsible div is folded or unfolded. Moreover, I would like to write multiple paragraphs within the collapsible div (above the row of buttons).

I tried several things, but I haven't figured out how to do this. It shouldn't be too hard, but I'm not a very good coder so I would appreciate it very much if somebody could help.

I already tried the following with bootstrap

```css
.block {
  position:relative;
}

.block .overlay {
  position:absolute;
  left:0; top:0; bottom:0; right:0;
}

.block .inner {
  position:relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block .inner a {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="accordion-item">
<div class="accordion-button block " type="button">
  <a class="overlay" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"></a>
  <div class="inner">
    <p>This entire box is collapsible.</p>
    <p>But somehow the arrow on the right side does not turn</p>
    <a href="https://duckduckgo.com/">I'm a clickable link that could also have been a button</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
   Exra information about the thing written above.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

The arrow on the right hand side is unfortunately not clickable and does not rotate.

Comment: So a card that redirects on click, and an arrow on right that collapses/un-collapses it. What exactly will get collapsed though (since you said the bottom buttons are visible always)?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain very well. I only want redirection upon clicking the link. I want the div to be able to unfold anywhere I click (except for the link). The thing that gets collapsed can for example contain more information about the thing that is written in the collapsible div. My code snippet does everything I want except that the arrow does not rotate, while it should. Also, when I click on the arrow nothing happens, which I also cannot solve.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you to read this page of Bootstrap docs:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/

Here there is all you need.

Comment: I can't find how to put links within the clickable (or collapsible) div in this documentation.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of collapsing, but if you want to redirect the clicker to the author's page, he'll not see the collapsing

```js
let card = document.querySelector('.card');

card.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  card.classList.toggle('active');
  })
```

```css
.card{
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out all;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.collapse{
  display:none;
  height: 250px;
}
.card.active{
  height: 300px;
}
.card.active .collapse{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p> post </p>
  <div class="collapse">
   
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
    <p>likes ............</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: if you want to set the collapsing on a button inside the card, just change the event listener to it BUT not the class toggling

**ANOTHER EDIT**:
to use it in [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/), you can customize it

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="card card-body" style="cursor: pointer;" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  <p>card</p>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

if you want to set the collapsing on a button inside the card, just add these attributes `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"` to the button

```js
let icon = document.querySelector('.icon');

icon.addEventListener('click', () => {
  icon.classList.toggle('flip');
});
```

```css
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  outline: none !important
}

.icon svg {
  transition: .2s ease all;
}

.icon.flip svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="card card-body w-70" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <p>card</p>
  <button class="btn icon" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-chevron-down"><polyline points="6 9 12 15 18 9"/></svg>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but this is not what I mean. I do not want the likes... to be unfolded, but I would like them to be contained in the lower part of the clickable div.

Comment: I've added snippet that already does most of what I want, but I am not able to make it work correctly with bootstrap

Comment: bootstrap? ohh you need another code then, I'll take a bootstrap collapse, and customize it.

Comment: I also tried it with bootstrap collapse, but I also was not able to make it work. Moreover, I would like there to be an arrow on the right hand side of the div. I would appreciate it very much if you could help me :)

Comment: I'm here to help you man don't worry I'll add the arrow

Comment: The other edit you made works good, thanks. However, I would also like there to be a clickable inside collapsible (upper) card. For example the text <p> card with clickable <a>link</a> </p>

Comment: does [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/#example) solve your issue? check `Link with href`

Comment: and if you mean putting two collapses inside each other you can do it, keep in mind that the button and the collapse is moveable, you can also set 1 button for [multi collapses](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/#multiple-targets)

Comment: No because that link just becomes another way to unfold. I want there to be a link to a website (or something else) within the entire div that unfolds. When you click the link it goes to the website, and when you click anywhere but the link, the div unfolds

Comment: I will try to combine your and my code when I find the time. I will come back to this post. Thanks a lot for you help. Greatly appreciated :D

Comment: yeah if you don't know here there are accepted answers and this is very helpful to users here. You can just click on the `right` to accept answer IF it solved your problem